# How to Update All Documents in a Collection With Thousands of Documents in FireStore with Firebase Admin?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

**Updated to reflect Firebase-Admin, rather than v9**
**New Update: solution at the bottom**

How to update a single field (in a map) for all documents in a collection with thousands of documents -- in firebase-admin/firestore (10.0.2)? I attempted to use this:

```
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'
const db = getFirestore()

db.collection("users").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.ref.update({
        "words.subscription": 0
    })
  })
})
```

I use it within a Node.js (v12) cloud function. The function runs, I see no errors, but none of the documents are updated. Previously, I attempted to use `set()` because some documents may not have the field, but Frank let me know `update()` can update fields that don't exist too.

However, this updated code also does not update all the documents in the 'users' collection.

Thank you in advance.

**Update/Solution**
@Dharmara - thank you for the gist. It did not work as-is, so I decided to change to async/await and wrap it in try/catch (to hopefully find out why it wasn't working), like so:

```
try {
  let querySnapshot = await db.collection('users').get()

  if (querySnapshot.size === 0) {
    console.log('No documents to update')
    return 'No documents to update'
  }

  const batches: any[] = [] // hold batches to update at once

  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc, i) => {
    if (i % 500 === 0) {
      batches.push(db.batch())
    }

    const batch = batches[batches.length - 1]
    batch.update(doc.ref, { "words.subscription": 0 })
  })

  await Promise.all(batches.map(batch => batch.commit()))
  console.log(`${querySnapshot.size} documents updated`)
  return `${querySnapshot.size} documents updated`
}
catch (error) {
  console.log(`***ERROR: ${error}`)
  return error
}
```

When I tested this however, it worked. From what I can tell it's the same as the `then()` way you had in the gist (and from what I had found elsewhere in SO).

If you wanted to put this into an answer I'd gladly mark it as the answer. Your code helped tremendously. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using batched writes or updating individual documents using `Promise.all()`? Like `update()` returns a promise. Can you try running the function in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DharmarajX24/f73eda2da1c3d863100c7e6f58a6c558) ?

Comment: Good call by Djarmaraj on using `Promose.all` to ensure the calls to the database complete (as they're asynchronous). In addition, you may want to add `console.log` statements, or run the code in a debugger, to see which lines execute and with what values. That type of debugging information is useful for you, but also for us to help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Djarmaraj, thank you for the gist. It helped. Although it didn't work as-is, I adjusted the code to use async/await instead of `then()`. I also wrapped it in try/catch to see if I could find why it wasn't working -- but when I tested it, it worked! ;)

Frank, thank you for the help. You gave me more clarity in how `update()` also updates fields that don't exist (as long as the document exists). 

Comment: I wasn't sure if the parent function is `async` or no so I used `then()` for the first one. Funny how both comments misspelled my name in same way 

Comment: So sorry about the misspelling @Dharmaraj. 

Comment: HI All. I am having a similar issue within some of my functions. All my normal short running functions work perfectly but anything where I am doing large dataset update I get a function timeout and only a few records are updated.
Is there any other things I can try as I have the above code in and it only worked for about a week until we had another 3k signups.

Answer (score 2):

The dot notation you use to write a nested field only works when you call `update()`, not for `set()`. Luckily `update()` works for non-existing fields, it only requires that the *document* already exists.

So for the namespaced API of v8 and before that'd be:

```
doc.ref.update({
  "words.subscription": 0
})
```

For the modular API for v9 and beyond, it's:

```
update(doc.ref, {
  "words.subscription": 0
})
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for the clarify between `update()` and `set()`, that helps alot in other places in my code too.

Unfortunately, this is stil not updating all the documents in the "users" collection.

I'll update the question with the code I retried.